# Does android do a lossy compression when storing the image on disk, after a picture has been clicked on camera?

Tags: android, image

I took at photo from my motog3 phone's native camera app. The size of the image on disk is **2.7MB**. I loaded it into my application using

```
Bitmap.decodeFile(filePath, options)
```

The resulting bitmap is **9MB**. That is almost 3 times the size on disk. I presume that some sort of compression is done to store the image on it. 
But isn't JPEG compression lossy? SO, is android storing a lesser quality image onto the disk? Any information on how much quality is retained when compressing?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Bitmap simply takes more space (in RAM) than original image on disk.

**Update**:
In test I figured out, that it's really is. I created Bitmap (500x500, ARGB_8888) and     getAllocationByteCount() on it: result 1000000 bytes. Than i saved in on the disk without compression and got 4728 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

> I presume that some sort of compression is done to store the image on it.

Pretty much all raster image formats are compressed. An image file on disk will almost always be substantially smaller than the amount of RAM the decompressed image takes up. This is true for PNG, JPEG, WebP, GIF, and pretty much anything else that you will routinely encounter today.

> But isn't JPEG compression lossy?

[Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG).

> SO, is android storing a lesser quality image onto the disk?

*Android* is not doing anything. The camera app is writing the image to a file.

> Any information on how much quality is retained when compressing?

You can certainly [read more about JPEG's lossy compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_compression). Usually, a JPEG encoder will take some sort of "quality" parameter, usually in a 0-100 range, to indicate how lossy the compression can be. In your case, since you delegated the image capture to a camera app, the camera app is making a decision for what to use for this parameter, possibly based on user preferences supplied to that camera app.